# Extract specific html string from html source code(website) in vb.net

Tags: html, vb.net

Actually I have full html source code of the website ..I want to extract data between the specific div tag 
here is my code..

```
Dim request As WebRequest = WebRequest.Create("https://www.crowdsurge.com/store/index.php?storeid=1056&menu=detail&eventid=41815")
    Using response As WebResponse = request.GetResponse()
        Using reader As New StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())
            html = reader.ReadToEnd()
        End Using
    End Using

    Dim pattern1 As String = "<div class = ""ei_value ei_date"">(.*)"
    Dim m As Match = Regex.Match(html, pattern1)
    If m.Success Then
        MsgBox(m.Groups(1).Value)
    End If
```

Comment: Might be worth looking at the [HtmlAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/), as it will save you a whole lot of pain.

Comment: I also used html agility pack but i was not able to extract data from div ..then I have to use this...could you please tell me how i can extract div data using html agility pack

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An easier approach for parsing HTML (especially from a source that you don't control) is to use the [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/), which would allow you to do something a little like:

```
Dim req As WebRequest = WebRequest.Create("https://www.crowdsurge.com/store/index.php?storeid=1056&menu=detail&eventid=41815")
Dim doc As New HtmlDocument()
Using res As WebResponse = req.GetResponse()
    doc.Load(res.GetResponseStream())
End Using

Dim nodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='ei_value ei_date']")
If nodes IsNot Nothing Then
    For Each var node in nodes
        MsgBox(node.InnerText)
    Next
End IF
```

(I've assumed `Option Infer`)

Answer (score 0):

Try that:

```
Dim pattern1 As String = "<div class\s*=\s*""ei_value ei_date"">(.*?)</div>"
```

or

```
Dim pattern1 As String = "<div class=""ei_value ei_date"">(.*?)</div>"
```