# Search string and grab all contents between 2 key words VB .NET

Tags: regex, string, vb.net

I've seen a bunch of examples on this online but I can't seem to find the one I'm looking for which uses **Regex**. I've seen many that use a loop and use a lot of lines of code but I'd like to see an example of Regex.

What I'm trying to create is an app that will connect too a webpage take the source search for a keyword once its found copy the text from that keyword to another keyword and save it into a string or to a textbox whatever.

I'm already using web request to get the information and put it into a string I just need to search the string for what I am looking for.

The reason for this app is to search webpage for an updated version of some software I'm using. I want to monitor for updates and the app to notify me when an update is available. Just a simple app but having issues searching for what I need.

```
For Example:
first words to search for: Server 64-bit
second words/characters to search for: </div>
```

grab first words everything in between and last word saved into a string.

EDIT: The information I am trying to grab is this....

```
Server 64-bit
                  <span class="version">
          3.0.13.6
                      </span>
              </h3>
                    <div class="checksum">SHA256: c7eeb1937b0bce0b99e7c7e20de030a4b71adcaf09750481801cfa361433522f</div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extract specific html string from html source code(website) in vb.net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24755662/extract-specific-html-string-from-html-source-codewebsite-in-vb-net)

Comment: How is that a possible solution if I have to download something in order to make this work? There has to be a way with the original vb .net to do this without having to add third party to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the following code with `RegEx` to return the whole sentence including the two keywords you are providing

```
Dim str As String = "first words to search for: Server 64-bit second words/characters to search for: </div>"

str = str.Replace(vbNewLine,"|")
Dim strA As String = Regex.Match(str, "Server 64-bit(.*?)</div>", RegexOptions.Singleline).Value

Msgbox(strA)
```

Or you can use the following expression to get only value between this two keywords:

```
Dim strA As String = Regex.Match(str, "(?<=Server 64-bit)(.*)(?=</div>)", RegexOptions.Singleline).Value
```

Comment: I only need the very first instance of the content between Server 64-Bit and </div> there are others in the webpage but the only one I need is the very first one that it finds. Using your code its just not working I don't know why.

Comment: Neither one of the solutions here are working for me. I've edited my question and added the code I'm trying to grab from the html maybe that may help.

Comment: @Palumbo Use `regex.match` instead of `matches` it will return the first occurence. I updated my answer take a look

Comment: I am trying to use Dim webPage As String = WRequest("website.com", "GET", "") and then putting webPage int the str spot and it tells me that match can't be converted to string.

Comment: Use `match.value` chech my answer

Comment: When run the messagebox turns out to be blank. Nothing shown.

Comment: No when using match it didn't return anything no messagebox nothing.

Comment: the error is because the string contains `vbNewLine` character, you can do a workaround and replace it with another separator. check my answer

Comment: it worked , i used `Dim strA As String = Regex.Match(str, "(?<=Server 64-bit)(.*)(?=</div>)", RegexOptions.Singleline).Value`

Comment: Ty that worked. I was thinking it had to do something with the whitespace. I just figured vb.net would read past the whitespace and just skip it.

Comment: @Palumbo, though you got working solution, Regex isn't good approach in long time term. For example read this: [http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1565525](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1565525).

Comment: Yeah I realize its not the best but this program is for me and me only. The website I'm pursing is a very very well maintained and popular website. They will always have their html perfect so this works just fine for what I need and very simple amount of code. If I was doing a lot of html parsing I'd be using something different. Thank you though.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not the prettiest solution, but i would save it into a string. Then iterate through it with the string.contain("Server 64-Bit") and then split the whole thing and then split the remaining part of the string at the next  and retrieve only the first part.

```
Dim Information As String
Dim Splitstring As String
If Information.Contains("Server 64-Bit") Then
        Dim parts As String() = Information.Split("Server 64-Bit")
        For Each part In parts
           SplitString As String = part(1)               
        Next
   If SplitString.Contains("</div>") then
       Dim parts As String() = Information.Split("</div>")
       For Each part In parts
           Dim ResultString As String = part(0)
           'Displaying Result in a MsgBox
           MsgBox(ResultString) 
        Next
   End If
End If
```

Im currently only at my Phone, so I cant actually test this, but this *should* work.

Comment: IT won't work because you declared a string inside the for each and it can't be used in the next if statement. Will have to make the the SplitString public

Comment: for some reason neither your code or Hadi is working. I have edited my post to show the code I'm trying to pull from the html. Maybe that would help us figure out why.

Comment: hum...im not at my computer, could you run my code step by step and look at the value of the variables and maybe see where the mistake actaully is?

Comment: Splitstring is being used before its been assigned a value is one an error that it gives but even if I run it still doesn't get the info between the two keywords. Also says for the second if statement that parts hides a variable in an enclosed block. So two errors on the code.